# Nodemon breaks rollup's hot reload plugin

Tags: typescript, express, svelte, nodemon, rollup

I'm figuring out how to develop web apps fullstack. I use Svelte for frontend and Express.js for backend. I've configured everything so that the Express app serves the client the built application. Here's my `index.ts`:

```ts
import express, { Router } from "express"
const app = express()

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"))
})

app.listen(3000, () => {})
```

My `rollup.config.js` *(I've removed the `serve` function because I don't need it. Otherwise it's the same as a default rollup config for Svelte)*:

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

// function serve() {
//  let server;

//  function toExit() {
//      if (server) server.kill(0);
//  }

//  return {
//      writeBundle() {
//          if (server) return;
//          server = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
//              stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
//              shell: true
//          });

//          process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
//          process.on('exit', toExit);
//      }
//  };
// }

export default {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ sourceMap: !production }),
            compilerOptions: {
                // enable run-time checks when not in production
                dev: !production
            }
        }),
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file - better for performance
        css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),
        typescript({
            sourceMap: !production,
            inlineSources: !production
        }),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        // !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

My `package.json`'s script section:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "rollup -c",
  "dev": "rollup -c -w & tsc -w -p tsconfig.backend.json & nodemon dist/index.js",
  "start": "sirv public --no-clear",
  "check": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json"
},
```

In `dev` I'm starting `rollup`'s build process in watch mode, same thing for `tsc`'s process for `tsconfig.backend.json` and finally start the complied version of the backend server with `nodemon`.

So everything works *(though I'll admit it's clinky)*, but there is an annoying issue with my method. Whenever I make changes in any of my `.svelte` files, everything reloads without any issues, but if I change some code in my `index.ts`, the server reloads and my browser's page signals me that it have lost the connection to it *(the server)*. I then have to manually restart the page to connect to it. How can I make it so that my browser doesn't loose connection to the server when it reloads?

Edit: the server fails to hot-reload regardless of where the changes are made.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console or the network tab?

Comment: @unloco, no, any logs are erased with the server's restart

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after I've added a bit of delay to `nodemon`, everything was fixed.
`package.json`'s script section:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w & tsc -w -p tsconfig.backend.json & nodemon -d 1 dist/index.js",
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear",
    "check": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json"
  },
```

Notice the `-d 1` in `dev` next to `nodemon`.